# Grails with Team City

Tags: grails, teamcity

On my Grails project, I wish to use Team City for the build management.  I've read several blogs/documentation on how to get the builds with Team City, but I see that when you run regular Java unit tests, Team City is smart enough to give you a nice output saying tests passed and test failed.

When I run my Grails tests, either from ANT or using the command-line option, I only see a success or failure output.  This is probably because both are running test-app under the covers. Is there anyway to see the test passed/failed in Team City?   How does Team City know what tests passed/failed from ANT Java unit tests?

These are the sources where I found out how to get Grails running with Team City.
http://groovy.dzone.com/news/automate-grails-app-builds-tea
http://groovy.dzone.com/news/automate-grails-app-tests-team

Answer (score 1):

Nice thing is that Grails spits out XML, text or HTML test results which can be found in `.../target/test-reports` directory.

To integrate the reports into **TeamCity**, you'd go to your build configuration's **General Settings** and add an artefact path. i.e. `target/test-reports/html` (path may vary) which would upload all HTML reports to the server.

To view it, go to the build results page and click on **Artifacts** drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Grails plugin which hooks into TeamCity via the Service Message API to provide better integration:

http://grails.org/plugin/teamcity